# How could I default to nothing with argparse pointing to a pathname?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

Currently, I'm using `argparse` to output the following file:

```
import argparse
....
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='do cool stuff')
parser.add_argument('--output_text_file',                  
    default="outputs/output_file1.txt",
                    help='file path for the output text file')
```

This is already an optional argument. However, I would like the default option to be `do not output anything`. If the user would like a file output, they can call the argument with the pathname above, e.g. `--output_text_file "outputs/my_text.txt"

What is normally the correct way to do this?

I suspect that if I use:

```
default=""
```

there will be an error above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, just omit the default:

```
parser.add_argument('--output-text-file')
```

In the args, check whether the `output_text_file is None`.  *The name will always be present*.

Comment: > In the args, check whether the output_text_file is None. The name will always be present.

You mean, define this variable at the top of the script in the package? I may not be following you entirely

Comment: It just means that in the part of the code where you produce output, put a conditional branch that checks `if args.output_text_file is not None:` first.

Answer (score 1):

You could set your default to [os.devnull](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.devnull), it's a cross-platform value which corresponds to the file path of a null device

```
parser.add_argument('--output_text_file', 
                     default=os.devnull, 
                     help='file path for the output text file')
```

Comment: This would be for third-party software, so it's somewhat difficult to make this assumption

Comment: `os.devnull` is the correct way to find `/dev/null`.